# Rails, Heroku, ActionMailer, Sendgrid: Heroku Logs say Email Sent, but no Email Received

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, actionmailer, sendgrid

This is my first time trying to send emails with Heroku and I am really struggling to configure everything.I have been looking at this for hours and can't figure out why I am not receiving emails. I have looked everywhere online and can't seem to find why my configureation isn't working.

Please, if someone could help, that would be very much appreciated.

My `product.rb` file:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'acebros.herokuapp.com' }

config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  port: '587',
  authentication: "plain",
  user_name: ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  password: ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'heroku.com',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

An example mailer:

```
default from: "acebrosdev@gmail.com"
def quote_email(user, quote)
    @customer = user
    @quote = quote
    @url = 'acebros.herokuapp.com/' + quote_status_path(@quote)
    #attachments['quote.pdf'] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
                           #render_to_string(:pdf => 'quote', :template =>
                           #'quotes/quote_attachment.html.erb')
                           #)
    mail(to: @customer.email, subject: "Quote ID: ##{@quote.id}")
end
```

And finally, my heroku logs:

```
2014-12-08T17:56:38.121051+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/quotes/5/done" for 129.31.193.143 at      2014-12-08 17:56:38 +0000
2014-12-08T17:56:38.241873+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered quote_mailer/quote_email.text.erb (0.4ms)
2014-12-08T17:56:39.684236+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://acebros.herokuapp.com/quotes/5
2014-12-08T17:56:39.683035+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to annikamonari@gmail.com (1093.2ms)
2014-12-08T17:56:39.683029+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-12-08T17:56:39.684436+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 1560ms (ActiveRecord: 26.9ms)
2014-12-08T17:56:39.692999+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/quotes/5/done"  host=acebros.herokuapp.com request_id=0c19e839-1d20-43ee-9e27-8ba657eb3637 fwd="129.31.193.143" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=1572ms status=302 bytes=1246
2014-12-08T17:56:42.352091+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by QuotesController#show as HTML
```

Comment: Any chance it's asynch (in a background job)?

Comment: I'm not really sure what that means or how I can even check that?

Comment: What controller#action sent the email?  Are you using devise?  Any bg job gems installed? (delayed_job, Sidekiq, resque)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the fix. They had temporarily disabled my sendgrid account, and the email, automatically generated by the heroku config, didn't match my email and so I didn't receive it. Had to contact customer support. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Check your SendGrid email activity in the SendGrid dashboard to make sure it's being sent: https://sendgrid.com/logs/index